# Generated a reusable APEX component from a Page

Tags: plugins, oracle-apex, reusability, region

I want to save myself some time (I have two weeks of my internship left) by creating a simple reusable component based on a Region I created for a reporting page.

[image: Component]

It consists out of a Static Region with the collapsible Template, containing 3 very similar Diagrams.

There is one Value which is the same for all 3 Diagrams, and 2 Values I need to change for each diagram.

Any tips how to reach that goal? Copying is dreadful, since I need that component 19 times on this page. I have no experience with creating plugins for APEX.

Comment: Hi Timo, did you still need help with this? Did you see Ian's answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have already created the region you can duplicate it as many times as you like on that page by right clicking the region in the Rendering Tab on the left side of Page Designer and clicking the Duplicate option from the menu:

[image]

This is a lot faster than recreating the region from scratch each time. You can also do this to duplicate buttons, page items and dynamic actions.